# Possibility to ping test dual sim 3G networks simultaneously?

Tags: android, ping, 3g, android-networking, dual-sim

I have built an app to schedule ping service continuously for the connected network using parameters like timeout and timeintervals between pings from the user. The app works fine. I had a doubt about dual sim phones. How do I do the ping operations on both connected networks simultaneously? Is it possible?

Kindly provide any source code or guidelines of how to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Dual-SIM phones I know you will not run into trouble because there is only one 3G data connection at a time. Some devices use the second SIM card only for 2G/phone connections.

If there is really a phone that supports two 3G data connections at the same time the system must allow the user to specify how the connections are used. The common way would be to set routes so that connections to certain IP addresses are routed through SIM 1 or 2. Alternatively each app would be bound to a certain SIM card/connection.

In both cases you don't have to care about this in your app and you have no way to influence it.